# Header repeat issue in pdf on row span

Tags: javascript, css, angular, pdf-generation, primeng-table

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v6.1.7/#/table
I have added three css properties in order to make thead repeat for primeng table

```css
.ui-table .ui-table-thead {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-before : always;
  page-break-after : always;
  // thead th { position: sticky; margin-top:0.3em; top: 0; }
}
```

html to pdf Output
[image]

But the **problem** in above output is, that **bottom line** appears before second page and first **th** background color of **thead** is getting white, because I'm using row span on that.
is there any solution to ignore the page break specifically before that row start

Comment: Showing your CSS and not the actual structure of the content is worthless. It appears (but is totally unclear) that you have a table inside a table.

Comment: @KevinBrown there is only one table as shown in output.
I've used the cell as row span simply.